# Intellij No Tests Found Kotlin

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, kotlin

I am trying to work through the Kotlin Koans in Intellij Idea Ultimate 2017.2 and I am having issues running the tests. I have marked the test directory as such, but when I try to run them as a whole or individually with the triangle arrow in the gutter that Intellij adds to tests I get a "No tests were found" error.

Screenshots are attached.

[image: Filepath]

[image: Gutter]

[image: Error]

Comment: Did you find a suitable answer?  I am wondering the same...

Answer (score 1):

> I have marked the test directory as such, but when I try to run them as a whole or individually with the triangle arrow in the gutter that Intellij adds to tests I get a "No tests were found" error.

You have it marked (incorrectly) as a **test resource**, not **test source**. Make sure to open the project by [importing from Gradle](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#gradle_import) then IDE will automatically configure the project structure and set the [folders categories](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-root.html#root_types) as needed.